# Why Mathematica is returning a complicated output rather than a simple one (as in the screenshot)

Tags: equation-solving

I am using Nsolve to get output on my thread of equations. I have two screenshots attached here. I was supposed to get the same result as pic#1[image], rather than pic#2. Can someone help me with how can I make my answer according to Pic#1?
Also, I'm getting the warning "Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result."

```
    ClearAll [u, v, f1, f2, \[Mu]]
f1[\[Mu]_] := \[Mu]*\:f0006*u + 5*v\:f006 - 3*u^2 - 4*u*v - v^2;
f2[\[Mu]_] := -10*\[Mu]*u - \:f0002 + 9*\[Mu]\:f006*v - 10*u^2 - 
   10*u*v - 3*v^2;
eqns = Thread[{f1[\[Mu]], f2[\[Mu]]} == 0];
steadyStates[\[Mu]_] := 
  Chop[NSolve[Thread[{f1[\[Mu]], f2[\[Mu]]} == 0], {u, v}]];
steadyStates[-2.99]
```

[image]

Comment: If you look in the definition of f2 (third line of your code), one mu is blue instead of being green. Maybe that's the reason? Also it's better to paste the code instead of a snapshot.

Comment: When you want your car to be repaired, you bring it to a workshop, not just show a photo to the mechanics. When you want your question to be answered, you post your code, not just a photo of it.

Comment: @yarchik
Got it man.. thank you

Comment: @Walser Thanks, I got it .

Comment: Why are your parentheses blue? I’m not sure that is the source of your problem, but they shouldn’t be blue?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
f1[\[Mu]_] := -3*u^2 - 4*u*v - v^2 + (6*u + 5*v)*\[Mu]; 
f2[\[Mu]_] := -10*u^2 - 10*u*v - 3*v^2 - 10*u*\[Mu] - v*(2 + 9*\[Mu]); 
eqns = Thread[{f1[\[Mu]], f2[\[Mu]]} == 0]; 
steadyStates[\[Mu]_] = Chop[NSolve[eqns, {u, v}]]; 
steadyStates[-2.99]
```

You don't need SetDelayed in the function steadyStates

Comment: Thank you very much.. I really appreciate It. It's working.